# how to do variable stack trace in phpstorm?

Tags: php, debugging, variables, phpstorm, stack-trace

I have xampp with xdebug installed and using phpstorm.  I wanted to know how to do a variable stack trace in phpstorm debugging session?  basically w/o extra hardcoded xdebug functions into the code how do i do so in phpstorm debug session?